# qt drag and drop with restriction to child rectangle

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I try to implement a drop-based selection where the user can drop elements on differnt places inside a widget to start some process.
I started by looking at the Qt DropSite example and changed it by adding a further label with a size of 60x60px to the DropArea. Then I changed the method `DropArea::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)` according to the example in http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html (section *Drop Rectangles*) while `label` is my equivalent to the mentioned `dropFrame`.

```
DropArea::DropArea(QWidget *parent)
    : QLabel(parent)
{
    setMinimumSize(200, 200);
    setFrameStyle(QFrame::Sunken | QFrame::StyledPanel);
    setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
    clear();

    label = new QLabel("Target", this);
    label->setFixedSize(60, 60);
    label->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    label->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Light);
    label->move(80, 60);
}

void DropArea::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
  if(event->answerRect().intersects(label->geometry()))
  {
    setText(tr("<drop content>"));
    setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Highlight);

    event->acceptProposedAction();
    emit changed(event->mimeData());
  }
}
```

According to the documentation, one has to accept the QDragEnterEvent inside dragEnterEvent in order to receive dragMoveEvents. I accept the event but this changes the cursor to the copy data symbol immediatelly after entering the DropArea and the drop action is accepted on the whole widget not only the label.

Do I have to handle the cursor changes by myself or is there some detail I overlooked to allow Qt handle the process properly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get the question correctly. However I'll give it a try.

Whenever I try to catch events like drag&drop at not subclassed standard widgets I prefer using event filters.

```
DropArea::DropArea(QWidget *parent)
: QLabel(parent)
{
  // ... stripped your example just showing the difference
  label->installEventFilter(this);
  label->setAcceptDrops(true);
}


bool DropArea::eventFilter(QObject *pFilterObj,QEvent *pEvent)
{
  if ( (pFilterObj == label) && (pEvent->type() == QEvent::DragEnter) )
  {
    QDragEnterEvent *dEvent = (QDragEnterEvent*)pEvent;
    if (dEvent->mimeData()->hasText()) dEvent->acceptProposedAction();
  }
  if ( (pFilterObj == label) && (pEvent->type() == QEvent::Drop) )
  {
    QDropEvent *dEvent = (QDropEvent*)pEvent;
    qDebug() << dEvent->mimeData()->text();
  }
  // give the default handlers a chance to act too
  return false;
}
```

If you are using multiple drag&drop labels in your application though it's better to subclass QLabel and overwrite the drag and drop events. You can do that even if using Qt Creator. Just add a regular label there and eit it's properties to be a placeholder for a custom class.